# How to convert Session attribute converting to long in java?

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
long orgId = (Long)request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId");
```

I am not able to convert the object that I am getting from `request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId")`
to long variable

So I need to convert it to long.
Could anyway help.

Comment: long orgId = (Long)(request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId")).longValue();

Comment: Are you sure the data stored in `session#getAttribute("orgId")` is from `Long` type or is in `String` format?

Comment: The only problem I can foresee is that you haven't set the `orgId` attribute and it returns `null` so you're code fails. Of course, we could give you a right answer if you edit your question and post the stacktrace of the error instead of just say *I am not able to foo the bar*.

Answer (score 1):

This way is not the best way to proceed, it's too prone to error (and you are assuming orgId value is present as session's attribute and unboxing, in case orgId is null/not present, will throw an exception).

```
final long orgId;
Object sessionValue = request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId");
if(sessionValue != null) {
  if(sessionValue instanceof Long)
  {
    orgId = ((Long)sessionValue).longValue();
  }
  else if(if(sessionValue instanceof String) {
    orgId = Long.parseLong((String)sessionValue);
  }
  else {
    // you can set orgId = 0, throw exception, do custom conversion
  }
}
else {
  // manage missed value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the type of the "orgId" attribute. If it really is a Long, your code should work. If you've for instance added it as a String, you need to convert it to a long with [Long.parseLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29):

`long orgId = Long.parseLong((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId"));`

Answer (score 0):

This the common way to do this

```
String strOrgId = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId");
```

Then parse this value to [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29)

```
long orgId = Long.parseLong(strOrgId);
```

Comment: [`HttpSession#getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) returns an `Object`, so if the `orgId` attribute is stored as `Long` this code will fail.

Comment: This is assuming that the attribute stored is a `String`. The `HttpSession` is (essentially) a `Map<String, Object>` so if the attribute is stored as a `Long` this will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how is your "orgId" stored in session attributes, as a String instance or a Long instance.

Following code is little bit redundant but will work for both cases:

```
Object attribute = request.getSession().getAttribute("orgId");
long orgId = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(attribute));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.. I stored a long in the session, and when I wanted to get the attribute it was automatically deserialized to an Integer OR Long dependent on their size. This was really annoying..

So in my case the solution was to convert to a string and than parse it to a `Long`:

```
Object orgIdObject = session.getAttribute("orgId");
Long orgId;
// first, make a null check. you'll never know
if (orgIdObject == null) {
    // if value is null, set to -1 or throw and error..
    orgId = -1L;
} else {
    // convert to string, and then parse to long
    orgId = Long.valueOf(orgIdObject.toString());
}
```

In this way, it does not matter if the Object is a String, Integer or Long. It works with all that types.

Happy Coding,
Kalasch